iOS SQLite database name no longer 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28?
Trying to extract the SQLite db from my iOS phone. Used IExplorer to download the directory Media/Library/SMS but could not find the expected file name 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28. Has it changed?


How does the screenshot relate to the question? What other files are there in .../Media/Library/SMS?

I think the sqlite messages database is usually found in one of these directories 00 0a 0f e.t.c  and by the name 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28  but I can't seem to find it.   Not sure where I should be looking

Did you look in the 3d directory?

for sure.   :-(   no joy.

nobody can help me determine the new location of the file?   I can see software that is reading the texts so I know it is there.  I just can determine the raw path to be able to query the sqlite tables - please help
